# One-liner to save value of if statement?

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Is there a smart way to write the following code in three or four lines?

```
a=l["artist"]
if a:
    b=a["projects"]
    if b:
        c=b["project"]
        if c:
            print c
```

So I thought for something like pseudocode:

```
a = l["artist"] if True:
```

Comment: It seems that you are dealing with a nested dictionary. You can use `get()` attribute in order to get the values for a specific key which, accepts an default argument to be return if it couldn't found the key.

Comment: Do you actually care if `a` and `b` are set as long as the value of `c` is printed?

Comment: `l.get("artist", {}).get("projects", {}).get("project", None)`, though that isn't particularly more readable.

Comment: What does your data look like exactly, does `l["artist"]` always exist, and if it's not an empty dictionary, then "projects" always exists and so on?

Comment: @chepner no i just want to return c later on

Comment: @RemcoGerlich artist does always exist. everything later doesn't automatically exists, that depends on the artists settings.

Comment: I suspect that if you have this happen once in your code, then I'd just leave it like you have it. And if you have to do this kind of thing often, make a helper function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't necessarily think that this is better but you could do:

```
try:
    c = l["artist"]["projects"]["project"]
except (KeyError, TypeError) as e:
    print e
    pass
```

Comment: Probably better to use `except KeyError`.

Comment: This is not functionally the same. OP's code will throw exceptions if the key is missing.

Comment: That's more likely a shortcoming of the OP's code than a desired side effect, but that is some context that is missing from the question.

Comment: The other difference is that if for example `l["artist"] is False` then OP's code does nothing.

Comment: In particular, if the final value is falsy, his code doesn't print and yours does.

Comment: @freakish indeed, I agree that it is not the same ... I'm not exactly sure if that was the intent though

Comment: @JulienSpronck thanks, but that raises an keyerror, thats not what I want.

Comment: @JulienSpronck I originally didn't want to print anything that was just a test case. I read an xml and want to return an empty array so Ido somethin like c=[] in the except case. So your answer did bring me to the solution... thanks!

Comment: @Florian I changed the code, so that it doesn't raise an exception anymore. I had done it to be closer to your original code.

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
try:
    print l["artist"]["projects"]["project"]
except KeyError:
    pass
except TypeError:
    pass # None["key"] raises TypeError.
```

This will `try` to `print` the value, but if a `KeyError` is raised, the `except` block will be run. `pass` means to do nothing. This is known and EAFP: it’s **E**asier to **A**sk **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission.

Comment: this raises TypeError "NoneType" has no attribute "__getitem__"

Answer (score 0):

```
p = l.get('artist') and l['artist'].get('projects') and l['artist']['projects'].get('project')
if p:
     print p
```

You can also make a more general function for this purpose:

```
def get_attr(lst, attr):
    current = lst
    for a in attr:
        if current.get(a) is not None:
            current = current.get(a)
        else:
            break
    return current

>>> l = {'artist':{'projects':{'project':1625}}}
>>> get_attr(l,['artist','projects','project'])
1625
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner (as in the title) without exceptions:

```
if "artist" in l and l["artist"] and "projects" in l["artist"] and l["artist"]["projects"] and "project" in l["artist"]["projects"]: print l["artist"]["projects"]["project"]
```

Comment: `else pass` will raise a SyntaxError (it' not an expression)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich fixed

Comment: That's really long for a one-liner; I'd at least use `if l.get("artist", False) and ...` to combine both the access and truthiness test for each key.

Comment: @chepner yeah I know... all the other guys went for "smart", I just went for "one-liner"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with nested dictionaries, you might find this generic one-liner useful because it will allow you to access values at any level just by passing it more `keys` arguments:

```
nested_dict_get = lambda item, *keys: reduce(lambda d, k: d.get(k), keys, item)

l = {'artist': {'projects': {'project': 'the_value'}}}

print( nested_dict_get(l, 'artist', 'projects', 'project') ) # -> the_value
```

Note: In Python 3, you'd need to add a `from functools import reduce` at the top.